# Emacsclient cannot connect to running emacs daemon

Tags: emacsclient, daemon

I have a problem connecting to my emacs daemon.
Here is the situation :
I am on nixos
I have an emacs-29.1 daemon running with "emacs-29.1 --daemon" as a user service.
Here is the output of `systemctl --user status emacs.service` :

```
    ● emacs.service - Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/user/emacs.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2023-10-18 13:40:34 CEST; 23s ago
      Cntrl PID: 38419 (emacs)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 37048)
     Memory: 118.5M
        CPU: 2.811s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/emacs.service
             ├─38419 /nix/store/5y4cbsar66ajyqx69mi8a77sdm6zah02-emacs-29.1/bin/emacs --daemon
             └─38420 /nix/store/5y4cbsar66ajyqx69mi8a77sdm6zah02-emacs-29.1/bin/emacs --daemon
oct 18 13:40:34 VS-thinkpad systemd[1392]: Starting Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor...
oct 18 13:40:36 VS-thinkpad bash[38420]: tsc-dyn-get: Using source :github (:loaded nil :recorded 0.18.0 :requested 0.18.0)
oct 18 13:40:36 VS-thinkpad bash[38420]: tsc-dyn-get: Recorded version already satifies requested -> loading
oct 18 13:40:36 VS-thinkpad bash[38420]: tree-sitter-langs: Grammar bundle v0.12.49 was already installed; skipped
```

This indicates me that the daemon is correctly running and in the correct version.
I then try to connect with `emacsclient -c` but here is the output :

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

--socket-name
--server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
--alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Note that `emacsclient --version` outputs : `emacsclient 29.1`

I have tried to find the socket-name and found it with `C-h v : server-socket-dir`.
I ran the `emacsclient` providing it with the socket but it does not exist when emacs is not running (with `emacs`).

Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

EDIT :
output of `emacs --daemon` in the terminal

```
tsc-dyn-get: Using source :github (:loaded nil :recorded 0.18.0 :requested 0.18.0)
tsc-dyn-get: Recorded version already satifies requested -> loading
tree-sitter-langs: Grammar bundle v0.12.49 was already installed; skipped
```

Note : even with `emacs --daemon` started, `emacsclient -c` cannot connect to it. I have the same output as above.

Comment: The daemon may have problems starting the server. What happens if you start an interactive emacs without `--daemon` and then try to start the server manually with `M-x server-start`? If there are problems with that, fix them and then try the daemon invocation again.

Comment: @NickD it says "Restarting server" and then I can connect to the daemon with `emacsclient -c` and it works without any issues.

Comment: Try adding `(server-start)` at the end of your init file. That might convince the daemon to start it even if it had trouble initially. Ultimately you'll have to debug it to get to the root of the problem, but that might be a reasonable workaround for now.

Comment: What output do you get when you invoke `emacs --daemon` from a terminal ?

Comment: @TristanRiehs I edited my question to include the outputs of the command

Comment: @nick I added it. (server-mode) is now enabled and emacsclient can connect to it while the emacs frame that spawned the daemon is alive.

Comment: It appears that the command terminates properly. I had issues with Tree-sitter when I went from Emacs 28 to Emacs 29. The `emacs --daemon` command stopped when it reached the Tree-sitter config (maybe related to the fact that Tree-sitter became built-in). Try removing your Tree-sitter configuration to see if it is the culprit.

Comment: @TristanRiehs that fixed the issue, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED :

Using tree-sitter in the config file caused the issue. Removing it fixed the problem.

EDIT :
I believe I found how to use the built-in tree-sitter and not crashing the daemon thanks to the official page of the module (https://emacs-tree-sitter.github.io/) provided in the comments by @Tristan_Riehs

To enable tree-sitter without disturbing the daemon I use :

```lisp
(global-tree-sitter-mode)
(add-hook 'tree-sitter-after-on-hook #'tree-sitter-hl-mode)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using tree-sitter in the config file" please?  That seems like you've narrowed the issue down further, but I think it's safe to say that people using tree-sitter shouldn't have the problem you were having.

Comment: If https://github.com/emacs-tree-sitter/elisp-tree-sitter is the tree-sitter support you were using, then it might be worth discussing it in their issue queue.

Comment: @phils the tree-sitter I was using is tree-sitter.el (which I believe is the native one)

Comment: @phils I am using doom emacs and even tho I can enable the tree-sitter module without problem in the init.el file. Configuring it in config.el (even adding hooks) was causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds more like https://github.com/emacs-tree-sitter/elisp-tree-sitter/tree/master/lisp -- but you can simply visit the library inside Emacs and see whether it's in your config or part of the core Emacs install.

Comment: @phils It might also be a package manager issue. The thing is that if you try to use the `tree-sitter` package that is not built-in to Emacs while using Emacs 29+, which is explicitely forbidden [here](https://emacs-tree-sitter.github.io/), problems occur. The `tree-sitter` configuration has to be written in a way that the built-in feature is used if it is available.

Comment: @TristanRiehs I read through the page you provided and I managed to configure tree-sitter correctly so that it uses the built-in version. Thank you